# Make an Android ActionBar's ActionView's Width match the ActionBar's width

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to show an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) that is always expanded in my `ActionBar`. This is my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/visibility_menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/visibility_search" />
</menu>
```

This is my `layout/visibility_search.xml`

```
<AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/visibility_search_auto_complete_text_view" />
```

This is my Activity:

```
public class VisibilityActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(layout.visibility_activity);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.visibility, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

I'm using `showAsAction="always"` because I want the `AutoCompleteTextView` to always be visible (it will be the only thing in the `ActionBar`).

My `AutoCompleteTextView` is always right-aligned in the `ActionBar` and only has 100px width. Why is this?

**Update**

Thanks to [Atul O Holic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22824436/9636), I found a preferred solution for my case, which doesn't require any special logic at all. I'm leaving [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840600/9636) as correct because it works for the general case, but for my specific case, a `SearchView` is better and easier.

Comment: Does it have to be an `AutoCompleteTextView`? have you seen [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)? `SearchView` will expand and collapse when the user taps on it and it has functionality to provide a list of suggestions.

Comment: I want it to be expanded all the time. There will be nothing else in the `ActionBar`, so making the user tap the icon to expand a `SearchView` is just needless work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[theelfismike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22824436/9636) pointed me in the right direction, but I was able to simplify it a bit. The answer he linked to referred to displaying a custom view with [`ActionBar#setCustomView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)), whereas I'm trying to make an action view set with [`MenuItem#setActionView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29) take up the full width. It is possible that my simplification won't work well for `ActionBar` custom views.

This is the xml that worked for me:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/visibility_search_edit_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately, this hides the `ActionBar`'s title. [An answer in the question theelfismike linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070383/9636) referred to this problem, but I couldn't get the [suggested workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517395/9636) to work.

Also, `RelativeLayout` seems to be the required root of an action view. I tried using a `LinearLayout` with many different combinations of `layout_gravity` and `layout_width`, but I couldn't get a `LinearLayout` to fill the full width.

Comment: this actually didn't hide the title for me. worked out. thank you

Comment: Thank you! Your comment on RelativeLayout saved me some time.

Comment: Thank you man... I just wrapped my LinearLayout inside the relative layout and it works perfect...!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this solution: [How to display custom view in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar)

I think I had to do something similar.

I think the magic parts are that it has to be a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout and have this attribute set: `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"`

Comment: Do you know how to prevent this from hiding the `ActionBar`'s title?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Emmanuel in context of using SearchView as it's an in-built View and is meant to Search. :) It also goes along well specially with ActionBar.

```
I want it to be expanded all the time.
```

Adding the below will always keep it expanded by default (unless user himself closes it),

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

We can also add auto-suggestions to SearchView via a ContentProvider. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) a doc from Google on the same. You may also like [this.](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-suggestions-to-search/)

Give it a shot. Have Fun. :)

Comment: I don't want to give the user the option to un-iconify. I'm going to stick with an `AutoCompleteTextView` because it seems simplest for now, but this looks like something good to try. Thanks!

Comment: I tried `SearchView` and it has `SearchView#setIconfiedByDefault`, which when set to `false` prevents iconifying. This is the exact behavior I want. I'll update the question.

Comment: Glad it gave you a hint for the right track. :D Mission successful. :)